# Merge tag "swift-generics" into tag "generics"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

- [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) used for *20,825* questions
- [swift-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-generics) used for *71* questions

There's no reason for [swift-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-generics) to exist.  Moreover, [.net-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-generics) has already been merged into [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics).

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/generics/synonyms

Comment: Cue generic comment saying that that tag is too... generic?

Comment: What about java-generics?  Is it somehow more useful than swift-generics and .net-generics?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I was not aware of [tag:java-generics].  It should probably be eliminated also.